# Global variable persists even when app is closed

Tags: android, android-activity, global-variables

I have declared a class extending Application to keep a global variable between activities of my app. When I press back from my launcher activity (FirstActivity.Java) my app closes, but the value of variable still remains same, which i do not want. How to achieve it?

> Please note - FirstActivity extends BaseActivity
>
> I am creating this whole setup to show a **pin activity** that asks for pin whenever app starts or comes to foreground from backGround. So I have setup flag to false in `onStop()` so that pin shows up when it checks the flag in `onStart();`

I did following -

**BaseActivity.Java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    //static boolean flag = true;
    Context con;
    private ApplicationActivity app;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        app = (ApplicationActivity)getApplication();
        Log.d("pin", "on Create base");
        con = this;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("pin", "on start 1");
        if(app.isFlag()){
            //Start pin activity here - if pin is true it sets flag to false  
        app.setFlag(false);
        }

    }
```

**ApplicaitonActivity.java**

```
public class ApplicationActivity extends Application{
    private boolean flag = true;

    public boolean isFlag() {
        //SharedPreferences sp = new SharedPreferences();
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
```

**FirstActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
//private Bundle savedInstanceState;
    Context con;
    Button nextActivity;
        
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        //this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        Log.d("pin", "on Create 1");
        con = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the value will change?   I can see nothing in your code to do this. `When I press back from my launcher activity (FirstActivity.Java) my app closes` - how are you accomplishing this?  I mean, how are you "closing" the app.  I think you might be misunderstanding Android here.  You do not "close" apps anymore than you "close" a website.

Comment: You can initialize variable on app start.

Comment: I did some messy editing. Check now in `BaseActivity - app.setFlag(false);` will do change it

Comment: @PurpleDroid I haven't published the whole code, but my logic wants me to check the value of flag in onStart() itself, depending on what I perform some action.

Comment: Your app is still enjoying the OS attention when you press back from my launcher activity. If you Force Stop this App from settings, your variable will be used as you want. Otherwise, you can use onPause() call back in your launcher activity to reset this variable. But still, if user presses Home Key is any of your Activities(other then : launcher activity), you still will have this issue.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. You should only use `SharedPreferences` if there is a need to persist values between instances of your app.  The extended `Application` class is a singleton and is the correct way (or at least, one correct way) to hold none persisted global state - although one should always question the design since global state is very often a bad thing.

Comment: i want variables to vanish once I close the app.

Comment: Darpan, please read about the activity lifecylce at developer.android.com.  As Eu.Dr. says, onPause() will probably do everything you need it to but onStop() and onDestroy() might also be useful).  `onStart()` is only called if your app is a new instance.  Simply pressing back does not close it.

Comment: I have read/made a POC/ understood activity lifecycle thoroughly. Since the activity we are working on is an activity that other activities will be extending. Setting the variable `false` `onPause()` did surely worked; but for that, I had to set the variable value `true` at `onStop()`, `true` at `onDestroy()`, `false` at`onBackpressed()` and `false` at `onFinish()`. I will post the final code soon. 
Even I find this solution a quick and dirty one. But this is the only one working I have found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to set the variable which still keeps the same to null or to reset the variable when you leave the App.

You can use this

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    yourVariable = null;
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    yourVariable = null;
}
```

Also i would recommend to use `SharedPreferences` to set global variables through your whole app.

Comment: It is a checkPin activity, so I have this obligation to set the variable as true in onStop(); and false in onDestroy(); anything in between will change the logic.